# MySQL help … Error message occurring on file download?

Tags: php, mysql, calendar, icalendar

I'm running the following script to try and create individual calendar events for every course and list those that have booked as ATTENDEES. When I run the script I get a .ics file downloaded but when opened I get this error message *"Calendar can’t read this calendar file. No events have been added to your calendar."*

```
  require_once('calendar.php');
    $start = date('Ymd', $row['CourseStartDate']) . 'T' .date('His', $row['CourseStartDate']) . 'z';
    $end = date('Ymd', $row['CourseEndDate']) . 'T' .date('His', $row['CourseEndDate']) . 'z';
    header("content-type:text/calendar;charset=utf-8");
    header("content-disposition:inline;filename=bookings.ics");
        echo "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n";
        echo "VERSION:2.0\n";
        echo "METHOD:REQUEST\n";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "BEGIN:VEVENT\n";
        echo "UID:".date('Ymd') . 'T' .date('His').rand()."firstaid4life.com";
        echo "DTSTAMP:".date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."/n";
        echo "DTSTART:{$start}\n";
        echo "DTEND:{$end}\n";
        echo "SUMMARY:{$row['CourseTitle']}\n";
        echo "ATTENDEES:{$row['Attendees']}\n";
        echo "END:VEVENT\n";
    }
        echo "END: VCALENDAR\n";
```

Comment: well it will always download as an ics regardsless off having any errors because your header is set that way. so even an html page with php errors will download as an ics file and ofcourse you can't open that, you should output the data before setting the header to make sure the data is as you want it

Answer (score 0):

Open it with a text editor or comment out your headers to see the originating error (perhaps you will recieve no results .. hence no rows)

As addition .. the UID is pretty random, why not hash some bits so the UID is consistent on each download?

Comment: I opened up the .ics file in brackets and it listed all the events accurately in the following format … #'s represent data I dont want to share.

`BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:20150915T09341310723401########DTSTAMP:20150915T093413/nDTSTART:19700101T003335z
DTEND:19700101T003335z
SUMMARY:#############
ATTENDEES: ### ###, ### #####
END:VEVENT `

I'm not sure if the time is rendering in the right format?!?

Also DTSTART & END are reading as 1970 which is not correct.

Comment: 1970 mostly indicates that the unixtime of the date is zero (0)

which is correct as $row does NOT yet exist at 
date('His', $row['CourseStartDate']) . 'z'
as far as you have shown all your code.